# Gradient with specific height and gravity

Tags: android, android-drawable

I need to create a drawable with a gradient (10dp) on the right of the screen.
I need to do this using drawable because I have to apply it on a single layout...

This is what I need:

[image]

Using two layout is very easy to do, but I need to use just one.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For that create one Custom View or Layout in on Draw you have to draw the gradient so it will looks as you specified

For more information have a look at this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

If you have any samples google it about gradient usage.

Comment: So it it impossible using a drawable?

Comment: No it's not impossible try you may get